# How to transfer data from one table to another with exception handling in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, insert, cursors, excel, exception

So, I have two tables, one where I import data from an excel file all in string format without considering any sorts of constraints or data type validation. And then the data is transferred to the actual table where those data are stored in proper structure.

I have something like

```
insert into "actualtable" (cols)
select cols
from "dumptable"
where condition;
```

Now I want to handle exception, for example, I want to determine the type of error occurred during transfer and update the `dumptable` with proper status message for each row, which will be shown to the client so that they know what specific row of their excel file has what specific problem.

How do I do that? I wanted to do something like

```
exception when <specific exception> then
    update "dumptable" set status = <message based on exception> where "id" = <exceptionRowId>
```

But I am unable to identify the `exceptionRowId` thing.
Is there a way to do that?

Since the excel files are really huge (millions of rows), I thought something like this would be preferable over looping over a cursor. Correct me if I am wrong, and suggest the best approach.

Comment: How does the rest of your code look? It should be easy if you loop through the rows with a cursor.

Comment: There are millions of rows, and I thought if a single query could do it, I would rather avoid using cursor to take less amount of time as cursor loops across rows and runs multiple insert queries, which is slower. I am indeed using cursor as a workaround solution. Just wondering if it is possible without cursor.

Comment: I don't think that is possible without a cursor. You are right that it will be slower with a cursor.